# Bitwise operator on registers on MSP430 without dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, cpu-registers, msp430

I'm using an MSP430G2553 and TI have some helper code defined in headers that I'm using (msp430g2553.h). So for example if I want to set the direction of GPIO pin 0 of port 1 I can write

```
P1DIR |= BIT0;
```

Out of curiosity I looked at how P1DIR is defined. And I found

```
SFR_8BIT(P1DIR);
```

where SFR_8BIT is defined as

```
#define SFR_8BIT(address)   extern volatile unsigned char address
```

So we get

```
extern volatile unsigned char P1DIR
```

The value of P1DIR is added at link time and it's defined as (in the linker script):

```
P1DIR              = 0x0022;
```

So finally we get

```
extern volatile unsigned char 0x0022;
```

So to me it looks like P1DIR is a pointer, which means that we should have to
dereference it. But in all docs I look they do bitwise operators straight on the
P1DIR instead of *P1DIR. How is that possible?

Comment: `P1DIR` is not a pointer type at least per the declaration above, it would be pointer if it is defined as `extern volatile unsigned char *P1DIR`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yes, you are right. But to me it looks like the value of P1DIR is an address, just as the value of a pointer is an address. So can we do bitwise operation on a pointer value without dereferencing the pointer if we first cast it to a int/char? Maybe there is something else happening in the link stage that I'm missing.

Comment: In this case then, I think I would need to cast P1DIR to a pointer and then deref it to do bitwise operation on it, like  *((char *) (P1DIR)) |= BIT0;. Okay maybe that makes sense after all, casting it to a pointer and then dereferencing eliminates each other.

Comment: `casting it to a pointer and then dereferencing eliminates each other` no this is incorrect. doing so actually deref the `0x0022` location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
> extern volatile unsigned char P1DIR
> ```

... declares `P1DIR` as a `volatile unsigned char`, not a pointer to one.  There is no problem with performing bitwise operations on such an object.

I am also inclined to think that you misunderstand the linker script.  You say

> The value of P1DIR is added at link time

, but although I don't know the particular linker script language in question, it is a *link* language.  Surely, then, if the script contains ...

> ```
> P1DIR              = 0x0022;
> ```

... then that is defining the address corresponding to that symbol, not its value in the C-language sense.  That has nothing to do with the type of the value stored there.  Associating addresses with symbols is what linking is all about.

Presumably, then, `0x0022` is the address of an I/O port.  When the program reads the value of `P1DIR`, it is reading a value from that address and therefore from the port, which presumably exposes the value of a status register or similar.  It is not reading the address itself.

Comment: Great answer, thanks I get it now. I misunderstood the linker stage. The linker doesn't set the value of P1DIR, it sets the location. Looking at it in hindsight, extern volatile unsigned char 0x0022; doesn't even make sense, I mean where did the variable name go... :)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees the P1DIR as a variable, as you correctly traced, it sees P1DIR like this:

```
extern volatile unsigned char P1DIR
```

That is a variable which it's address is defined elsewhere. In this case probably in the standard library which will be used on the link step.
In the linking step the address of the variables are resolved, and P1DIR is taken from where ever it was defined as 0x22.
This kind of variable need to be on an specific addres, as it need to be at the defined address for that port.
You can check the address of every port in the MSP430 documentation (in there it is stated that P1DIR is at 0x22)